# asp.net integrate facebook login

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-login

Hi i am using facebook login authenticate in my local application.But at last when i click on facebook image it shows this error:

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

I know its domain name error that i have set in facebook aap url and site url.

i have set same url in IIS and facebook app .still i got error.

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login Authentication Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
} (document));

// Init the SDK upon load
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '553530488015828', // App ID
        channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel', // Path to your   Channel File
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
            FB.api('/me', function (me) {
                if (me.name) {
                    document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
                }
            })
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
    $("#auth-logoutlink").click(function () { FB.logout(function () {   window.location.reload(); }); });
}
</script>
<h1>
Facebook Login Authentication Example</h1>
<div id="auth-status">
<div id="auth-loggedout">

<div class="fb-login-button" autologoutlink="true" scope="email,user_checkins">Login  with Facebook</div>
</div>
<div id="auth-loggedin" style="display: none">
Hi, <span id="auth-displayname"></span>(<a href="#" id="auth-logoutlink">logout</a>)
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add unique facebook app id to use facebook login authenticate in your localhost. And you need to specify url in https://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: Technically you *can*, but you need to create a separate Facebook App to do it.  You can create a unique Facebook App for each target environment in which the code will run and include that App as part of the overall "environment" for that code.

Comment: Hi Ozan i read somwhere that we can use IIS custom url for localhost?

Comment: Where it gets really weird is when you try to use OAuth in something like a Win8 app where the return URL isn't even `http` but some in-app URL.  OAuth providers have a tendency not to like that.

Comment: @David can you tell how i can set this in local host??

Comment: @aman: Set what?  The approach Ozan and I are essentially recommending is that you create a second Facebook App and set the URL in that app to be your development URL (in this case localhost).  If you have a QA environment or any other environment as well, you should create a separate Facebook App for that environment too.  Consider the Facebook App to be part of the overall "big picture" of any given target environment.